# Difference between the main and the test folder in Maven

Tags: maven

I am a bit confused on the difference between the use of the folder main and the folder test in Maven. As of now, I just copy and paste my source code in both of them and it works fine. I don't get what the point of having another folder with exactly the same thing as the main folder is? Can someone please explain this to me.

Also:

- What is the difference between install and compile.
- So for this command: mvn archetype:generate, is generate the goal? then what is archetype?

Thanks

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html: `main`: application sources / resources while `test`: test sources / resources. That's all there is to it. You're asking like 4 or 5 unrelated questions here. This has nothing to do with install or compile phases. And this has nothing to do with archetype.

Answer (score 1):

The `main` folder contains your application code and resources, and the `test` folder contains, well, test code and resources. So don't copy your application code there, but only the tests. The test sources are then automatically added to the classpath in the test phases.

For the difference between `install` and `compile` have a look at https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html. Basically install also contains compile and a lot more goals (like execution of tests, packaging, installing into local repository.

`generate` would be the goal, correct. `archetype` is the short form for `maven-archetype-plugin` and means the plugin, which contains the goal. By default plugins with the name pattern `maven-*-plugin` or `*-maven-plugin` can be shortened that way.

Comment: So the point of the tests is to pretty much "test" experimental code to later be implemented into the stable version?

Also, does that mean that in mvn clean, clean is a plugin?

Comment: For clean, there is also a clean plugin, which is mapped to the clean phase. If you just type mvn clean, you execute the phase, if you type mvn clean:clean you would execute the goal clean from the clean plugin (which will be automatically called by mvn clean).

Comment: What is the difference between mvn clean and mvn clean:clean? and what are unit tests? sorry to bother you so much.

Comment: `mvn clean` calls the phase `clean`. `mvn clean:clean` calls directly the plugin with the goal. Regarding unit tests, i don't know what programming background you have, but if you don't know that they are, you should start with some basic tutorial, e.g. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Comment: mvn clean calls the phase? I thought clean was a lifecycle?

Comment: Lifecycle is the word for the whole thing and consists of all phases, as one of the headlines in the linked article says: "A Build Lifecycle is Made Up of Phases"

Comment: What if you call the cycle itself though? Like instead of calling mvn deploy, you call mvn default?

Comment: That doesn't work. You can only call phases or goals.

Answer (score 1):

- Separation between `src` and `test` folders is a standard practice where same package structure under both guarantees your `com.some.Class` finds its way and it's visible when `com.some.ClassTest` unit test runs.
- Difference between `install` and `compile`. Read the documentation around [the Maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). Essentially everytime you are invoking one **build phase**, every other build phase defined before it in the lifecycle gets called in the defined order.
- [Documentation about what is Archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html)